# Unexpected Response from my server while accessing it from a Client application in Silverlight

Tags: c#, wcf, silverlight-4.0

I am working on a silverlight application. While adding a server referrence, some times the server is returning an error message with out updating its services like

[image: Error]

I dint understand why its returning like that, and when I tried to give the same address in a browser its returning the server xml file correctly, and I am able to run the server from another browser also. Can any one give me a suggesstion to overcome this type of exceptions. I also tried by removing queries from my link like `"http://112.148.1.130:8000/"` but still its not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be that you are using the system http stack instead of the browser http stack. You can change this by calling the `WebRequest.RegisterPrefix` method. Refer to [this MSDN blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/silverlight_sdk/archive/2009/08/12/new-networking-stack-in-silverlight-3.aspx) for more information.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But I am not using any code to access the server. Directly adding the referrence to service through Solution Explorer.

Comment: I see. But is this exception occurring only when you add the reference or does it also happen when you are running the application? And does it only happen sometimes?

Comment: Yes, when I am adding the referrence to my project at that time its adding, but when I update it by right clicking on it, it is showing the above given error.

Comment: In your application config file, make sure you configure `proxyAddress`, `proxyAuthenticationScheme` and `useDefaultWebProxy` for the binding. I think the `useDefaultWebProxy` should be set to `true`.

Comment: I think, actually for referring to a Server from Client, no need to enable any proxy in config entries, by defualt it should take.

Comment: I agree that normally default proxy settings should be used, but it appears that this is not the case. Therefore you could try to add these entries in the config to see if it makes a difference. Especially the `useDefaultWebProxy` settings may sometimes be necessary to configure manually.